# Stata: can't use "if" in ivprobit?

Tags: stata

I'm trying to run ivprobit on Stata and I need to limit the sample. My code is as follows:

```
ivprobit exercised varlist (logRealSalaryOpDiff_actual = varlist2) if(fa2==1 & position_alt !=1 & year>=2003 & club_or_vest==1 & year==(yr1-1))
```

where I substituted long lists of variables with varlist and varlist2. However, when I try to run the regression, I get the error "r(101): if not allowed". When I remove the if condition, the regression works. I'm confused as the ivprobit documentation says that "if" is allowed. What am I doing wrong here? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to put a space between if and the logical expression for the constraint:

```
webuse laborsup, clear
ivprobit fem_work fem_educ kids (other_inc = male_educ) if (_n>23)
ivprobit fem_work fem_educ kids (other_inc = male_educ) if(_n>23)
```